# How to add delays in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I want to add a delay like so:

```cpp
std::cout << "loading..." << endl;
//add delay here
```

Is there some kind of `delay` function or a
`delay` library

Comment: I hope that this is just "for example's sake", because you shouldn't make the "loading..." part of a program *artificially* slower than necessary to... well... *load* whatever needs to be loaded. ;-)

Comment: Yes.. this is just "for example's sake" because I really need it for handling a few things in `thread`s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [std::this_thread::sleep_for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for).